# Area of portion of sphere

Tags: geometry, limits

Consider a spherical curved surface. It will have some radius of curvature, say R, now as we flatten the surface its radius will increase and so will its area will increase (at least according to the formula. Surface area directly proportional to radius squared ) And if radius tends to infinity surface becomes plane. But according to formula area will also tend to infinity, but area is finite as sheet is only flattened. Where is the fallacy?

Comment: If you consider a circle on the plane it has finite area. If you scale it in such a way that the radius goes to infinite then the area goes to infinite. There is no fallacy at all.

Comment: How precisely will you flatten the sphere ? How will it look like in the end ?

Comment: To what formula are you referring?  How are you selecting the part of the sphere at various radii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yves says, you have to say precisely how you flatten the triangle: Because of Gaussian curvature, this flattening cannot be done without some amount of distortion.

That said, if I understand right, the picture in your mind looks like this:

[image: Flattening a spherical triangle by growing the radius]

If that's right, the fallacy is:

> *As the sphere expands in radius, the triangle **subtends the same spherical angle** at the center of the sphere*.

Instead, the spheres are all tangent to a particular plane (containing the green triangle). As the sphere's radius grows, the center moves away from the vertices of the blue triangle, so the blue triangle's sides subtend angles roughly inversely proportional to the radius.

Consequently, the blue triangles have roughly constant area.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fallacy lies in your particular application of the idea of surface area increasing by the square of the radius. Let's recall the full context that this Law is stated in:

> Given a sphere (or a section of a sphere) with radius $R$, if you **enlarge** it, its surface area will increase in proportion to $R^2$.

But in your case you are stretching or deforming the object, not *enlarging* it as the Law states.

However, it is true that we can assign a so-called "*radius of curvature*" to an object that makes sense no matter what we happen to be doing to the object. Does this Law of Surface Area have any bearing on the notion of *radius of curvature*? To see, let's examine a simplified case: an arc of a circle being flattened into a line segment.

The Law there states that if you enlarge $R$, the *arclength* $s$ of the circle arc increases proportionally. Precisely, it increases by the law $s = \theta R$ where $\theta$ is the angle of the arc (measured in radians).

In *flattening* the arc into a line segment, we are not changing $s$, the arclength, but we are changing $R$, the radius of curvature. Using the now more generalized law of $s = \theta R$ I stated before tells us that the reason $s$ is *not* increasing though $R$ is increasing is because $\theta$, the angle of the arc, is *decreasing*. Indeed, as you flatten and flatten the arc, its *angular length* decreases in such a way that $s$ remains constant ($\theta$ tends to $0$ as $R$ tends to $\infty$ in perfect cancellation to produce a constant $s$)!

You can take this principle up to the spherical sector you were originally considering, except there, instead of using our standard idea of *angle*, we have to use something called a [*Solid Angle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle), which you can basically think of as the *percentage* between the area of your spherical sector and the area of the extrapolated sphere that would *contain* it (except $4\pi$ represents the max instead of $100\%$). As you flatten your spherical sector, the *percent* area of the imaginary sphere containing it *decreases* in exact proportion to cancel out the growth of the radius of curvature $R$. Thus the surface area can remain constant, and the generalized Law is not violated.